# "exec: 15: update-grub: not found" error when updating kernel

Tags: system-installation

```
root@me-desktop:~# sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aircrack-ng
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 446 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,579kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,843kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe aircrack-ng i386 1:1.1-1 [1,579kB]
Fetched 1,579kB in 1min 9s (22.7kB/s)                                          
Selecting previously deselected package aircrack-ng.
(Reading database ... 520739 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking aircrack-ng (from .../aircrack-ng_1%3a1.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic (3.0.1-030001.201108060905) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.1-030001-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.0.1-030001-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.1-030001-generic
exec: 15: update-grub: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up aircrack-ng (1:1.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@me-desktop:~#
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f` and edit your first post using the appropriate tag for the code.

Comment: no thing happan it is same problem

Comment: not only aircrack-ng ,

Comment: today i try some program it is not successfully install always asking same problem like : -  update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.1-030001-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
and : - Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@me-desktop:~$  like this massage coming and stop so please help me how to solve so please give me command, thank you verry verry much

Comment: E: linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
for this massage come from synaptic package manager, when i try to install some thing this massage appear and stop installation so please give me solution

Comment: **[E: linux-image-3.0.1-030001-generic: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2]**  for this massage come from synaptic package manager, when i try to install some thing this massage appear and stop installation so please give me solution

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

appears the OP is using this to track issues instead asking additional questions

Answer (score 0):

Not that its any of my business, but using aircrack is kind of illegal. also, make sure your system requirements for aircrack is right. aircrack only works on certain hardware chips